# Cocos3d: Texture not displaying

Tags: cocos3d

I have created a Cocos3d iOS project and facing issue on texture display. My project has been kept under this link-> https://www.yousendit.com/download/UVJpWmdzTkwzMW40WjhUQw
If we run this project, we can see a sample house model output, where roof shows in plain white color in the house. But, actually i have added a roof texture in blender, and converted in pod. I don't know why the roof texture display not displaying when running the code in simulator. Could please download my sample project https://www.yousendit.com/download/UVJpWmdzTkwzMW40WjhUQw and suggest me. This project source also contains the .blend, .dae, .pod files which its using.

```
CC3PODResourceNode* podRezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName: @"RobotPODRez"];
podRezNode.resource = [IntroducingPODResource resourceFromFile: @"DieCube.pod"];

// If you want to stop the robot arm from being animated, uncomment the following line.
//  [podRezNode disableAllAnimation];

podRezNode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO;
podRezNode.location = cc3v(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
podRezNode.isTouchEnabled = YES;
[self addChild: podRezNode];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAE files do not reference any textures:

**TestHouse.dae:**

```
  <library_images/>
```

So, you must have not exported them from Blender.

Comment: Its not TestHouse.dae, i named it as DieCube.dae for that house sample model. Can you please tell me how to correct dae file to be referenced to proper texture image? Its showing with proper texture in blender properly though.

Comment: Take a look at the section on DAE here: http://wiki.frictionalgames.com/hpl2/third_party_tools/3d/blender